# Upload files to drive - set new folder ID issue

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm trying to make an HTML to upload the files to drive. Each upload is creating a new folder. My problem is that I can't set the new folder ID for each upload. It's creating a new folder according to the input + Date. I'm saving a new folder ID on SS. How I can `.setParent` by the SS cell value on HTML?

**Code.gs**

```
/*   
Fetch the oAuthToken 
*/

function getOAuthToken() {
    DriveApp.getRootFolder()
    Logger.log(ScriptApp.getOAuthToken())
    return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
}


function doGet(){
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('drivePicker') 
      .evaluate()
      .setTitle('Upload Files')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);  
}

function createFolder(form) { 
   var nameBox = form.subfolder;
   var d = new Date();
   var time = d.toLocaleTimeString()
   var curr_date = d.getDate();
   var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1 ;
   var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
   var tDate = curr_year + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_date + " - " + time;  

   var dest = DriveApp.getFolderById("main Folder ID").createFolder(nameBox+" "+tDate);
   var destID = dest.getId();

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SS ID');
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Name");
   sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(destID);
}
```

**drivePicker.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <style>
        #attachmentTable { 
          background: white;
        }
        tr th,tr td {
          text-align:center;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body style='font-family: cursive;'>
    <div align="center">
    <h1>Please upload the files</h1>
    <p><img src="http://www.free-icons-download.net/images/upload-logo-icon- 
    68584.png" style="width:500px;height:500px;transform:rotate(0deg);margin- 
    top:50px"></p>
    <BR>

    <form>
      <input type="text" name="subfolder" id="subfolder" placeholder="Your name..">
    </form>
    <center><button onclick='formSubmit();getOAuthToken()' style="margin- 
    top:150px;outline:0;" class="btn btn-success">Upload File(s)</button> 
    </center>
    <div class='table-responsive' style="display:none;" id="attachmentTableDiv">
    <table id="attachmentTable" class="table table-bordered" 
    style="width:900px;margin:20px auto;float:none;">
      <thead>
        <tr style="background:#f1f1f1;">
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>URL</th>
          <th>Date Created</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
     function formSubmit() {            
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().createFolder(document.forms[0]);
            }
    </script>
    <script>
    var DEVELOPER_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; 
    var pickerApiLoaded = false;

    /**
     * Loads the Google Picker API.
     */
    function onApiLoad() {
      gapi.load('picker', {'callback': function() {
        pickerApiLoaded = true;
      }});
     }


    function getOAuthToken() {

      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createPicker).getOAuthToken();
    }

    function createPicker(token) {
      if (pickerApiLoaded && token) {

       var uploadview  = new google.picker.DocsUploadView().setParent('NEW FOLDER ID'); //How to set the ID from the SS cell A1 ?????
       var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            .addView(uploadview)
            //.addView(all)
            .hideTitleBar()
            //.setLocale('nl') //--Regional language settings
            //.enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
            .setOAuthToken(token)
            .setSize(536, 350)
            .setDeveloperKey(DEVELOPER_KEY)
            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
            .setOrigin(google.script.host.origin)
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
            .build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
      } else {
        showError('Unable to load the file picker.');
      }
    }

    /**
     * A callback function that extracts the chosen document's metadata from the response object. 
     */
    function pickerCallback(data) {
      var action = data[google.picker.Response.ACTION];
      if (action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        for(var i in data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS]){
        var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][i];
        var id = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];
        var url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
        var title = doc[google.picker.Document.NAME];
        var dateCreated = doc[google.picker.Document.LAST_EDITED_UTC];
        var date = new Date(dateCreated);
        date=date.toLocaleString();
        $('#attachmentTable tbody').append("<tr><td>"+title+"</td><td>"+id+"</td><td><a href='"+url+"' target='_blank'>Link</a></td><td>"+date+"</td></tr>");
        $('#attachmentTableDiv').show();
      }
    }
}
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script>google.load("picker", "1",{callback:function(){pickerApiLoaded 
  =!0}});</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obtain the value of the cell by using sheet.getRange("RANGE").getValue() and then pass that value by using [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).

Comment: @JustasKynas Hi. I'm looking at older questions that don't seem to have been resolved. How did you get on? Did you resolve your problem, or are you still looking for help?